# How to compile my objective c++ project when modules are enabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c++

My project uses objective c++. I have to enable modules but when I Set "Enable modules" to YES my project starts to prompt lots of errors that I don't know how to handle them. I have set "Build Active Architectures" to NO and added -fmodules and -fcxx-modules.
I have to mention that my project is pretty old (7 years).

Attached part of the error's log.
It looks like it messes up everything.

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmqZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your include paths somewhere.  The system-supplied header tgmath.h has a line that says `#include <complex.h>`.  That should be resolved as a "system" file.  Instead, your log shows it referencing something in another path (.../dmz_files/Eigen/.../Complex.h).

Contributing to the problem is the Mac file system, which doesn't do a good job of distinguishing between "complex" and "Complex".

The actual errors are coming from trying to interpret C++ code in an Objective-C context, but those are rather irrelevant compared to referencing the wrong file.

(Why this should be specific to modules, I do not know.)